# .htaccess rewrite from one file to another with URL parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been looking all over for this but the .htaccess syntax is still a cryptic language where I end up doing a lot of guessing-and-checking.

I'm trying to rewrite a request:

/folder/index.php?id=... -> /folder/index-new.php?id=...

I can replace index.php for reasons that are not worth explaining.  I want a redirect to index-new.php with parameters every time index.php is requested.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(folder)/index\.php$ /$1/index-new.php [L,NC]
```

`QUERY_STRRING` is automatically carried over to new URL.